# Disable Undertow/Wildfly from generating JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: cookies, java-ee-7, undertow

I have an application build with JavaEE7 and running in development via embedded Wildfly 9.0.2.Final as a maven plugin to startup application.

```
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0.Final</version>
```

I would like to disable Undertow/Wildfly from generating its own JSESSIONID in the response.

We are proxying requests to another downstream system and would like to use the same cookies that it is sending back to our app.

I tried setting the cookies in the response context via implementing ContainerResponseFilter but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

responseContext.getCookies().put("JESSIONID", new NewCookie("JESSIONID", "somevasfasdaskljl"));
}
```

Please let me know if any more information is required

thanks

Comment: It's a protection against session fixation. You could change io.undertow.server.session.SessionIdGenerator in your io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo to a custom implementation, that does what you want. There is a io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension SPI that allows you to access the DeploymentInfo.

Comment: Thanks. We were trying to avoid any container specific code inside the app but I'll look into that in more details.